# Difference of n dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to determine the difference of n dictionaries in the following scenario:
There are `n` dictionaries. Some of their keys match, but not all. Like this:

```
dict_a = {
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyC': 'valueC',
    'keyD': 'valueD',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
}
```

```
dict_b = {
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyX': 'valueX',
    'keyD': 'valueH',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
}
```

I want to be able, to tell if the value of a key is different from the value of the same key in another dictionary. In the examble above `keyD` should be returned, because its value is different in `dict_a` and `dict_b`. `keyX` should not be returned, as it only occurs in `dict_b` This is relatively easy with only two dictionaries, but what is the best practise to accomplish this with `n` dictionaries?

Comment: So to be clear, the key should *exist* in all dictionaries, and the *value* should be different in *at least one* of those dictionaries?

Comment: it really depends if you have the n variable. do you know up front how many dicts you have?

Comment: The key may exist in multiple dictionaries, it's unclear if it actually does. Whether the value indeed is different is to be shown. We don't know, but it is very likely that at least one value is different.

Comment: Yes, you got the n variable. Thus, you know how many dictionaries there are.

Comment: We want to know if there are eponymous keys with different values in different dictionaries. It's enough if we know, _if_ one of those exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the list of dictionaries to compare, and keep track of all keys you've previously seen and their values (done through the `orig.update()` call).

```
compare = [{
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyC': 'valueC',
    'keyD': 'valueD',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
},
{
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyX': 'valueX',
    'keyD': 'valueH',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
},
{
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyX': 'valueX',
    'keyD': 'valueH',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueB'
}]

orig = compare[0]
diffs = []

for comp in compare[1:]:
    for k in comp:
        if k in orig and orig[k] != comp[k]:
            diffs.append(k)

    orig.update(comp)

print(diffs)
```

.. outputs `['keyD', 'keyG']` which are the two keys that have differing values of the three dicts. Replace `diffs` with a dictionary and use `dict.values()` if you don't want the keys to show up multiple times (i.e. if you only need to know that they have changed, not how many times they've changed).

Answer (score 0):

You can create this simple `lambda` function to do so:

```
>>> diff_keys = lambda x,y: [key for key in x.keys() if key in y.keys() and x[key] != y[key]]

>>> diff_keys(dict_a, dict_b)
['keyD']
```

And to handle `n` other dicts, you can create another function that can do so like this one:

```
>>> def get_different_keys(original_dict: dict, other_dicts: list):
...     different_keys = []
...     for dict_x in other_dicts:
...         different_keys.extend(diff_keys(original_dict, dict_x))
...         original_dict.update(dict_x)
...     return different_keys

>>> get_different_keys(dict_a, [dict_b]))
['keyD']
```

Comment: I like the brevity of your solution. Nevertheless, it has one "malfunction". If new keys are introduced in another dictionary than `dict_a` (the _original_ dictionary) those aren't checked for differences. For example: `dict_f={'ABC': 'valueA'}` `dict_g={'ABC': 'valueB'}` This difference gets lost.

Comment: I misunderstood your question... I expected you have just one dictionary `dict_a` and other dictionaries that you want to compare the keys to... anyway gonna fix it now!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_a = {
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyC': 'valueC',
    'keyD': 'valueD',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
}

dict_b = {
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyX': 'valueX',
    'keyD': 'valueH',
    'keyE': 'valueE',
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
}

dict_c = {
    'keyA': 'valueA',
    'keyB': 'valueB',
    'keyX': 'valueX',
    'keyD': 'valueH',
    'keyE': 'valueO',    # <- here is additional difference
    'keyF': 'valueF',
    'keyG': 'valueG'
}

# Step 1: prepare list of all dict

dicts = [dict_a, dict_b, dict_c]

# Step 2: get all common keys 

ks = [set(i.keys()) for i in dicts]
ks_i = list(ks[0].intersection(*ks[1:]))
ks_i

Out[1]:  # here is the list of common keys
['keyB', 'keyE', 'keyF', 'keyD', 'keyG', 'keyA']

# Step 3: get set of values taken from the different dict by the same keys

unequal = [{i[k] for i in dicts} for k in ks_i]
unequal
Out[2]:                 #show set of values for same keys  
[{'valueB'},            # for keyB
 {'valueE', 'valueO'},  # for keyE
 {'valueF'},            # and so on
 {'valueD', 'valueH'},
 {'valueG'},
 {'valueA'}]


# Step 4: check if the length of set and chooe appropriate keys
# if the set has length >1 then it has different values inside

[ks_i[ind] for ind,v in enumerate(unequal) if len(v) >1]

Out[3]:
['keyE', 'keyD']
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is well documented and thus easy to understand.